# How to set present date depending on date format of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, browser, format

I have a date field in my application. In one browser I am getting in mm/dd/yyyy format and in another browser getting in dd-MMM-yyyy format. By default I have to assign present date. How can I set in jquery so that depending on format it gives present date.(Instead of browser specific conditions is there any other way?)

Answer (score 1):

You best way is to compute yourself your format or use any framework /library for that.
One of them is [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

toDateString() seems have as parameter the output format.

```
 var out = new Date().toDateString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

EDIT : Nevermind, either you do the awfull function either try moment.js

Comment: No it is wrong [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) there is no arguments possible for `Date.toDateString();`

Answer (score 0):

For better browser compatibility JavaScript date formats use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

use `moment().format("mm-dd-yyyy");`